# Sending email through PHP, pound symbol

Tags: php, character-encoding

I need to send emails using PHP's `mail()` function. The code I am using is this:

```
$email_message = chunk_split(base64_encode($email_message));
$headers = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

There is a pound sterling symbol in the email which is not handled properly, i.e. recipient receives incorrect symbol. As its to do with character encoding and I am not sure how to set it to tell the email client how the characters are being encoded and how to deal with the pound symbol correctly. Can this information be put in the headers?

Comment: Could you please provide more detail.  Specifically output, where is the pound symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you correctly setting the encoding on the email? This is done by setting

> 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'

in the message's headers.

Plenty of documentation here if you scroll down: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 2):

If you have pound signs coming out as Â then look below

```
$costsum = "£".$costsum;   (Does not work)
$costsum = "&pound;".$costsum; (Does not work)
$costsum = "#163;".$costsum; (Does not work)
```

One answer I found was this!

```
$costsum = "\243".$costsum;
```

The \243 is a pound sign in whatever encoding that is.
I tried all the pages with UTF-8 and that didn't work either.
It was used to email a spreadsheet.